# Moved Discussions in Chat don't show all Comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comment, chat

I noticed that not all comments are taken over to a chat discussion, but only those with whom you were chatting last. Discussions might be interesting with all comments.

Can we have a full transcript of the comment section to the chat?

It is possible (as [response to a system flag due to a large number of comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215888/non-backtracking-closed-walks-and-the-ihara-zeta-function-updated-with-partial?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment4573134_2215888)) as I just recently found by chance...

Comment: This seems highly reasonable and quite desirable.